# iOS Deep Link doesn't call any function from the AppDelegate

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm having an issue with Deep Linking. when I go to safari, In the url i enter `myapp://` and press Enter. it redirects me to the app.

However none of the function in the AppDelegate is getting called.

I need to take the parameters from the URL.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    print("Continue User Activity: ")

    return true
}
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleOpen url: URL) -> Bool {
    showSimpleAlertView("hahah", message: "adasdasds", withPresneter: self.window!.rootViewController!, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    return true 
}
```

As from the online tutorial, on of these 2 function should get called.

Comment: if it's running , nothing gets called. if i killed it and start, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions get called

Comment: share details of the tutorial you've used. Have you setup the custom url in info.plist ?

Comment: Yes i set up the custom URL in info.plist. the app opens when i enter the custom URL scheme in safari.

Comment: http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-deep-linking-in-swift/

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue today. After doing some research I learned there's a new method in iOS 13 that captures the deep linking URs. Within `SceneDelegate` try this:

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {

        if let deepLinkContext = URLContexts.first {
            print("the url \(deepLinkContext.url)")
            print("the options \(deepLinkContext.options)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `handleOpen` function was deprecated in iOS 9... Try this one instead:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
```

Comment: Finally it worked. Should I rely on this method even if the deeplink launched the app without being in background ?

Comment: I am facing issue whenever I am opening it from browser, above deleagte getting called after again and again and resulting in recursion. any idea?